# My MacOS Terminal doesn't allow me to execute Python commands without sudo

Tags: python, macos, importerror, sudo, macports

When I try to execute commands from the terminal, I keep getting an error with the description: `ImportError: / Symbol not found: / Expected in:`.
However, that error doesn't appear when I execute the same command with `sudo`.

For example:

`$ pip search matplotlib`

Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 104, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/search.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import SessionCommandMixin
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import parse_links
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .serializer import serialize
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/serializer.py", line 11, in <module>
    from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/xml/sax/saxutils.py", line 6, in <module>
    import os, urllib.parse, urllib.request
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 2619, in <module>
    from _scproxy import _get_proxy_settings, _get_proxies
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_scproxy.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib//libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
```

But when the same command is sudoed, it works:

`$ sudo pip search matplotlib`

Returns:

```
WARNING: The directory '/Users/ja_jagg/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

django-matplotlib (0.1)             - Matplotlib field for Django
matplotlib-stream (1.0.0)           - GCPDS: matplotlib stream
hangar-matplotlib (0.0.3)           - Matplotlib plugin for hangar
...
```

I get the same error executing `ipython` and many other commands:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_scproxy.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib//libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
```

I would appreciate any help on understanding the cause of this error, and how can I fix it. I have had to `pip install` some packages with `sudo`, which I understand is very bad practice, and I want to avoid it. Thank you.

---

**EDIT:**

This issue has been present before installing Anaconda.
I installed Anaconda recently, and have been a long time user of MacPorts. I have Python 2 and 3 installations in both distributions. I've been experiencing this issue for a few years, but hadn't been a problem until now.

When using a different IPython path from that in Anaconda, I get the same error:

```
$ which ipython
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/ipython

$ ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 17, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.ipapp import load_default_config
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 28, in <module>
    from IPython.core.magics import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .code import CodeMagics, MacroToEdit
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/code.py", line 23, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 2583, in <module>
    from _scproxy import _get_proxy_settings, _get_proxies
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_scproxy.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib//libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
```

***In both cases, the recurring element is th file `/opt/local/lib//libJPEG.dylib`.***

When I `ls` the file, it returns:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  15 Jan 13  2020 /opt/local/lib//libJPEG.dylib -> libjpeg.9.dylib
```

which I understand, is a symbolic link for the file:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  215064 Jan 13  2020 /opt/local/lib//libjpeg.9.dylib
```

Since the command works fine with sudo, and the problem file is in `/opt/local/`, I wonder if this issue has anything to do with MacPorts. Perhaps a system file that doesn't have sufficient permissions, or a corrupted `.dylib`.

In case it may be useful:

```
$ echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/usr/local/mysql/lib/:/opt/local/lib/libgcc:/usr/OpenMotif/lib:/usr/local/gfortran/lib:/usr/local/gfortran/lib/i386:/opt/local/lib/:
```

The apparent solution would be to uninstall MacPorts and do a clean install. However, that option would be quite drastic, as it would affect other processes that I need to access on a regular basis. I just want to make sure if that would be a reasonable action to take.

I would greatly appreciate any feedback on this. Thanks for your time and attention!

Comment: Honestly, it looks like your Anaconda environment is just screwed up somehow. I'd recommend looking up instructions on how to clean up all traces of it and reinstall it.

Comment: You seem to have Anaconda and other nonstandard components installed; please [edit] your question to clarify what you have installed and how. Also, did you edit your shell's startup files recently?

Comment: @triplee Thank you. No, I haven't edited my shell startup files. I just edited the question, adding more details to describe the issue. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: If running the commands with sudo works, you may have a disk permissions issue.  Apple removed the native way to repair disk permissions in OS X 10.11 with System Integrity Protection, but you can still repair disk permissions on your user files by following the steps in this article: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/mac-disk-permissions-repair .  If this doesn't work, you probably will need to reinstall MacPorts.

Comment: Why do you have `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` set at all, and what and why do you have in `/opt/local/lib/`? Removing that component from your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` will probably fix the issue, though if you have an incompatible library in that directory, perhaps you should simply upgrade or uninstall whatever it is that you have there.

Comment: On my pretty vanilla Catalina box, this library is in `/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib`

Comment: @tripleee  ***YES!! That fixed the issue. Thank you so much!*** I had set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` long ago when I had to install MATLAB. I remember editing that variable long ago to get around installing a package in MacPorts. I really appreciate your help in this issue. All the best.

Comment: By the way the final trailing slash in `/usr/local/mysql/lib/` and `/opt/local/lib/` is superfluous, and is the cause for the uncanny double slashes in the system messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_scproxy.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
>   Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
>   Expected in: /opt/local/lib//libJPEG.dylib
> ```

This happens when you have a case-insensitive filesystem (which is the default on Macs) and you have set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to a directory that contains a standard copy of libjpeg.dylib (such as the one you have in /opt/local/lib from MacPorts).

Apple's ImageIO framework contains a nonstandard copy of libjpeg.dylib (which Apple has capitalized libJPEG.dylib) which contains additional symbols not present in a standard libjpeg.dylib—symbols which ImageIO requires. Setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` tells the OS that you would like it to look for libraries in the path(s) you specified first instead of where it would look for them normally. This, combined with your case-insensitive filesystem, means that when /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO is looking for libJPEG.dylib, it finds /opt/local/lib/libJPEG.dylib instead of /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib.

The solution is not to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.